# YouTube API "ChannelSections" results don't match with channel?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So for the YouTube Channel Mindless Self Indulgence it has 4 sections on the home tab first section is they're music videos playlist, the 2nd section is albums which is a group of different playlists, then another playlist section and the last section is there uploads.

But when I do a channelSections api call I get like 20 different items and it has me scratching my head why.

Here's the api response https://notepad.pw/raw/w27ot290s

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channelSections?key={KEYHERE}&channelId=UChS8bULfMVx10SiyZyeTszw&part=snippet,contentDetails

Comment: I'm wanting to get all the sections on the home tab of the channel but confused that it shows up 20 items.. Maybe it don't work that way?

Comment: Welcome to stack please edit your question.  Please include enough of your code that we can test it as well as any issues you are having with your code.   Describe in detail what you would expect to see as opposed to what you are actually seeing.

Comment: Like this youtube channel https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChS8bULfMVx10SiyZyeTszw only has 4 sections (atleast with my region) do a api call I get 20 sections. I have noticed using a proxy in london there's less video in the music playlist, maybe some of them are region specfic... 

I tried some other channel and I got the same about of items as sections. Soo maybe there's just a protery for what region it is that i'm missing or maybe a parameter.. Hopefully I get it lol.. Ill update if i do

Comment: @KurtBlissZ **[edit] the question** with the results you mentioned in your comment. As DalmTo said in a previous comment.

Comment: Yeahh probably would of helped if I read the whole page on the channelSections.... It mentions about regions... Ill try to muster up something understandable and answer this later once I understand it more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured this out finally, I neglected to read the documentation on the channelSections api

here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channelSections

I was getting channel sections for all the regions where channel like music may more often have region specific sections... To filter these you need to also include the targeting object in the part parameter. If the section is region free (or atleast i assume) it won't have the targeting object so something to take into condertation when handling your api response and filter sectoins based on regions.

Here's my code just trying to get the data filtered in react app, not the most practical maybe but I fumbled through it:

```
const data = response2.data.items;
console.log("response2 data", data);
const filtered = data.filter(item => {
    if (item.targeting === undefined) return true;
    let test = false;
    item.targeting.countries.forEach(i => {
        if (i === "US") test = true;
    });
    return test;
});
```